# Twisted AMP Server is not receiving data

Tags: python, django, twisted

I have built a multiservice daemon on twisted, which one receive command from a django, and that happen is

1. The django view connect the amp server
2. DJango doesnt sent the command or AMP is not receiving the command

My question is What I am doing wrong

My code is:

**AMP Server**

```
from twisted.protocols.amp import AMP, Command, String

class AmpProcessor(Command):
    arguments = [('proto', String()),
                 ('imei', String()),
                 ('ip', String()),
                 ('port', String()),
                 ('cmmd', String())]
    response = [('answer', String())]

class AMPServer(AMP):


    @AmpProcessor.responder
    def processor(self, proto, imei, ip, port, cmmd):
        print cmmd
        self.factories['proto'].clients['ip'].sendMessage(cmmd)
        return {'answer': 'ok'}
```

**TAC File**

```
import os, sys
import ConfigParser
from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from listener.TrackerServer import TrackerFactory
from listener.AMPServer import AMPServer
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ServerEndpoint
from twisted.application.internet import StreamServerEndpointService

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(PROJECT_DIR)

path = None
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('protocols.cfg')

application = service.Application("tracker")

factories = {}

for device in config.get('protocols', 'keys').split(','):
    devicer = config.get(device, 'name')
    factories[devicer] = TrackerFactory(devicer)
    internet.TCPServer(int(config.get(device, 'port')), factories[devicer]).setServiceParent(application)

endpoint = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8750)
factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = AMPServer
factory.protocol.factories = factories
ampService = StreamServerEndpointService(endpoint, factory)
ampService.setServiceParent(application)
```

**Django View**

```
def send_fence_to_device (request):
    device_fence_id = request.GET['device_fence_id']
    device_id = request.GET['device_id']
    fence_id = request.GET['fence_id']
    fnc = Fence.objects.get(id=fence_id)
    dev = Device.objects.get(id=device_id)
    try:
        devLog = dev.devicelog_set.filter(device_id=device_id, status = True).order_by('created').reverse()[:1].all()[0]
        params = simplejson.loads(fnc.other)
        lttdlgtd = simplejson.loads(fnc.points)
        strCommand = ".geo.%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" % (params['identificator'], fnc.name[:4], round(float(lttdlgtd[0][0]), 4), round(float(lttdlgtd[0][1]), 4), round(float(fnc.radius), 4), params['time_to_arrive'], params['fence_class'], params['tolerance'], 1)
        d = connect()
        def connected(protocol):
            return protocol.callRemote(
                AmpProcessor,
                proto='TELCOMIP',
                imei=devLog.ip,
                ip=devLog.ip,
                port=devLog.port,
                command=strCommand)
        d.addCallback(connected)

        def saved(result):
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(result), mimetype='application/json')
            #print 'Registration result:', result
        d.addCallback(saved)
        #d.addErrback(err, "Failed to register")

        def finished(ignored):
            reactor.stop()
        d.addCallback(finished)
        reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=0)

        #return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(1), mimetype='application/json')
    except:
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(0), mimetype='application/json')



def connect():
    endpoint = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, "127.0.0.1", 8750)
    factory = Factory()
    factory.protocol = AMP
    return endpoint.connect(factory)


class DeviceUnavailable(Exception):
    pass

class AmpProcessor(Command):
    arguments = [('proto', String()),
                 ('imei', String()),
                 ('ip', String()),
                 ('port', String()),
                 ('cmmd', String())]

    response = [('answer', String())]

    errors = {DeviceUnavailable: 'device-unavailable'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only call `reactor.run` once per process.  I am guessing that you are calling `send_fence_to_device` once per request.  This means that it may work once, but all subsequent calls will fail.

If you are set on using Twisted reliably inside a Django application, [Crochet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crochet) might help.